# QRcode after scan redirect to custom link

Tags: php, url, redirect, qr-code

I'm working with QRcode at the moment so far it's so good i can scan it and get a result back from the database.

Im getting the data as follow :

```
$qrcode =  QRcode::png('
      number:' . $number. '  
      Name: ' . $name. ' 
      Lastdate : ' . $lastdate . '     
      check: ' . $check. '');
```

My question is how can i scan the QRcode and redirect it to an custom link and display it on the website

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Recently i have made one application like your requirement only. what you need to do is, what ever data displaying through QR code that data insert into database then you will get one record id and using that record id you can make custom URL with creating new php page.

your code:

```
$qrcode =  QRcode::png('
  number:' . $number. '  
  Name: ' . $name. ' 
  Lastdate : ' . $lastdate . '     
  check: ' . $check. '');
```

my suggested code:

```
array('number' => $number,
  'Name '=>$name,
  'Lastdate '=> $lastdate,
  'check '=> $check);
Insert this array into your database
grab inserted recored id.
$custome_URL = "www.yourwebsitename.com/qrcode_scanneddata.php?id=$record_id";
$qrcode =  QRcode::png("$custome_URL");
```

when ever you scan the URL automatically it will open in web browser.

Comment: i managed to do it an other way i just passed it in the first parameter $qrcode =  QRcode::png('website here');  thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by code like this

```
header('Location: '.$qrcode->url);
```

Comment: i managed to do it an other way i just passed it in the first parameter $qrcode =  QRcode::png('website here');  thanks for replying